# Why is my command block repeating a sound, and how can I make it play only once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a sound when someone passes over a block, but when I put the /execute command it starts making a sound many times when I sit on that block. Can I somehow make it play the sound only once?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! You should always specify the version you are playing, I suppose this is Java

Comment: I play on Java edition. Do you have any ideea how to solve my problem ? Pokemon master...

Comment: Sadly no, my knowledge with commands is basic

Comment: Ok, thank's anyway

Answer (score 1):

If the command block is set to Repeating mode, set it to Impulse mode.